# Migrating to 2.6 How to get an I don't care BodyParser?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

Before Play 2.6 I had some custom actions e.g. NoCache action where I only had to care about implementing the `apply` method i.e.

```
package actions

import play.api.http.HeaderNames
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.Future

/**
  * Custom Action composition implementation that disables client-side browser caching
  * by changing the response header of the response adding multi-browser no-cache
  * parameters. The composition can be done as follows:
  * {{{
  *
  *   def link = NoCache {
  *     deadbolt.SubjectPresent()() { implicit request =>
  *       Future {
  *         Ok(views.html.account.link(userService, auth))
  *       }
  *     }
  *   }
  *
  * }}}
  *
  * @param action The inner action
  * @tparam A Action type
  */
case class NoCache[A](action: Action[A]) extends Action[A] with HeaderNames {
  def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result] = {
    action(request).map { result =>
      result.withHeaders(
        (CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
        (PRAGMA -> "no-cache"),
        (EXPIRES -> "0")
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Now in Play 2.6 I get a bunch of errors because `Action` now needs overriding `executionContext` and `parser`. I see nothing in this 2.6 but further complexity but anyways ... I manage to override the former using `global` but I don't see a way to provide a simple implementation for the later.

How can I specify an I don't care `BodyParser` for my custom `Action`?

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

override def executionContext = global
override val parser: BodyParser[A] = null // <<<<<< what else here?
```

Comment: Have you followed the migration guide? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration26

Comment: @ViktorKlang thanks for the link. I had seen it before but couldn’t find the answer to my OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [section on the migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Migration26#Scala-ActionBuilder-and-BodyParser-changes) about it:

> The Scala ActionBuilder trait has been modified to specify the type of the body as a type parameter, and add an abstract parser member as the default body parsers. You will need to modify your ActionBuilders and pass the body parser directly.

It could be better worded, but anyway, the way you "pass the body parser" is using dependency injection. For example, from [actions composition docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaActionsComposition):

```scala
import play.api.mvc._

class LoggingAction @Inject() (parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) {
  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    Logger.info("Calling action")
    block(request)
  }
}
```

And later you inject your action in your controllers:

```scala
class MyController @Inject()(
  loggingAction: LoggingAction,
  cc: ControllerComponents
) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def index = loggingAction {
    Ok("Hello World")
  }

}
```

Of course, you can use the same approach in your `NoCache` action:

```scala
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent._
import play.api.http.HeaderNames._

class NoCache @Inject() (parser: BodyParsers.Default)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends ActionBuilderImpl(parser) {
  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (Request[A]) => Future[Result]) = {
    block(request).map { res => res.withHeaders(
      (CACHE_CONTROL -> "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"),
      (PRAGMA -> "no-cache"),
      (EXPIRES -> "0")
    )}
  }
}
```

Also, as you can see, we are not using the global execution context, but instead the one available through dependency injection. This is the default execution context for the application, so it is [easier to configure](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ThreadPools#Configuring-the-default-thread-pool) if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the implementations of `BodyParser` you could give the value of  `BodyParser.Empty`

```
override val parser: BodyParser[A] = BodyParser.Empty
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.7/api/java/play/mvc/BodyParser.html

Comment: Thanks! but this gives an error because here you are assigning a class to a variable. The real answer should be `override val parser: BodyParser[A] = new play.mvc.BodyParser.Empty().asInstanceOf[BodyParser[A]]`